# react-spring - set the initial value of an interpolation

Tags: react-spring

The following will animate from `1` to `2`.

```
const [props, set] = useSpring(() => ({ value:1 }));
set({value: 2});
```

However, let's assume Iwant the value to be instantly changed to `3`, and then animated to `2`, regardless of what it is currently. In other words, I'd like to avoid the smooth interpolation between 1 and 3.

```
const [props, set] = useSpring(() => ({ value:1 }));
set({value: 3, immediate: true}); //doesn't seem to work.
set({value: 3});
```

How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [props, set] = useSpring(() => ({ value:1 }));
set({from: {value: 3}, value:2, reset: true});
```